# GIT back to a specific commit id without deleting the history

Tags: git

Here is my commit log and I want to switch back to a specific commit id (for example Second),
When I use git checkout , it is ok but, I am no longer able to switch back to the last commit (Fourth).

HEAD points to the second commit and there is nothing after that when I log my commits.

How can I switch between my commits without deleting the history?

```
commit 61c71a9e5a6d9e29a4172e687172dd4b8523eb4a (HEAD -> main)
Author: mohhhe <mohhhe@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 25 19:08:36 2022 +0330

    Fourth

commit 9c3e8919cfa2c970f14056eef34ca12b49025f65
Author: mohhhe <mohhhe@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 25 19:08:13 2022 +0330

    Third

commit d33795596001197f382038a72d20faf0cfbe7ab7
Author: mohhhe <mohhhe@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 25 19:07:55 2022 +0330

    Second

commit 2fe7b1d8270fcfb41d73e69293da10734e37b069
Author: mohhhe <mohhhe@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 25 19:07:39 2022 +0330

    First
```

Comment: `git checkout d3379` will switch to `Second` (in a "detached HEAD" state), then `git checkout main` will switch you back to `Fourth`

Comment: "but, I am no longer able to switch back to the last commit (Fourth)." Why not? Please show your actual Git commands, because what you are describing so far sounds very easy.

Comment: when I use "checkout <commitId>" the head points to the current ID (Second). So when I log my commits, in log report the last commit is Second and all the commits after that (Third and Fourth)  is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### An alleyway analogy

Imagine, for a moment, that you're at the entrance to a narrow street or alleyway in a big city, surrounded by skyscrapers.  Looking down the alleyway, you can see a series of dumpsters.  Now, walk halfway down the alleyway and look ahead of you.  Half the dumpsters are gone!  Where did they go?  Nowhere: they're right behind you.

The same idea applies here: Git did not *delete* the commits you can't see.  You just can't *see* them.  Move back to a vantage point from which you *can* see them, and you'll see them again.

#### Reality, such as it is

In Git, a *commit* is a two-part entity: it holds a snapshot of all files—well, all the files that Git knew about, at the time you (or whoever) *made* that snapshot—and some metadata.  Each commit is numbered, with a big, ugly, random-looking hash ID, like `61c71a9e5a6d9e29a4172e687172dd4b8523eb4a` as shown in your output.

The hash ID is what Git needs to *find* the commit.  The commit itself is stored as a bunch of parts, using a *commit object* and other internal supporting objects.  The hash ID you see here is that of the commit object itself, which holds only the metadata: the snapshot is in a *tree* object, which has yet more sub-objects.  But you don't normally need to know this; what you *do* need to know is that Git has a big database holding all of its objects, each of which is numbered, and that Git itself *needs* the number to retrieve the object.<sup>1</sup>

Humans, however, are very bad at numbers.  What were those four hash IDs again?  It's not worth memorizing them anyway though.  Git offers you a very fast way to find *one* of those four hash IDs: the name `main`, which is easy for you to remember, finds *one* of those hash IDs.

Over time, the one hash ID that `main` finds may change, but right now, it finds `61c71a9e5a6d9e29a4172e687172dd4b8523eb4a` for you, and for Git.  That commit is the *latest* commit on the branch `main`.  It is by definition, *because* the name `main` holds that ID.  So if you want Git to find the *latest* commit on `main`, you can simply ask Git for `main`, and Git will look up the name `main` and find that ID and hence find that commit.

If and when you make a *new* commit, here's what Git will do (in some order or another; you don't really get to see if there's any particular order to this):

- Make a snapshot of every file that Git knows about.  To make Git see any *update* you've made to a file that Git *already* knows about, you must run `git add` on it.  To make Git see any *new file you created* that did not exist until now, you must run `git add` on it.  There's a lot more to it than this, but that's the first approximation to the reason you have to keep running `git add`: to tell Git that the *new snapshot* should use the *new or updated file*.
- Gather up a bunch of metadata.  The metadata Git will gather includes your name (as set in your `user.name` setting) and email address (from your `user.email` setting).  It includes the current date-and-time down to the second.  And, it includes the *currently most-recent commit*, whatever that is, on the branch you're on—in this case `main`.

Git writes all this out to make a *new* commit, which gains a new, unique, never-used-before, never-will-be-used-again, hash ID.  This hash ID must never occur in *any* Git repository except to be used to identify *this* commit that you just made right now.  (That's why the hash IDs are so big and ugly: so they can be unique.)

Git then *stores the new commit's hash ID in the current branch name*.  So now the name `main` selects your *new* commit—the one you just made.

---

<sup>1</sup>That's because this big database is a [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), with the hash IDs being the keys.  There's a slow method of walking the entire database and getting every <key, value> pair, but this takes many seconds, or even minutes, in a big repository: far too slow to be useful.  A key lookup takes milliseconds, so that's what you want Git to be doing.

---

#### Commits thus form backwards-looking chains

What this all means is that the *name* `main` *automatically and always* selects the *last commit* in the branch named `main`.  By definition, `main` is the end of the street / alleyway / superhighway / motorway / whatever it is.  You *add new commits* by making new commits while you're on that "road", and that extends the "road" a bit further.

Another way to show this is to draw the commits using uppercase letters to stand in for the real hash IDs.  Here, we have your original four commits, which we'll call `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` for short:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--main
```

The *name* `main` will "point to" (contain the hash ID of) the last of these commits, commit `D`.  Commit `D` has a snapshot—a copy of all the files, frozen for all time—and some metadata, and `D`'s metadata says that the *previous* commit is commit `C`.  We say that `D` *points to* `C`.

Commit `C`, of course, has a snapshot and metadata.  The snapshot holds the files that Git knew about at the time you made `C`, frozen for all time, and the metadata holds the date-and-time and so on, including the hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  We say that `C` points to `B`.

Commit `B` holds a snapshot and metadata too, and points backwards to commit `A`, which holds a snapshot and metadata.  But commit `A` was the *very first commit* you made, in what had been, up until you made `A`, a totally-empty repository.  So commit `A` doesn't point further backwards: it can't.

That's how your four commits are, in your repository.  They can never change!  They are completely read-only, and those four hash IDs are now used up forever.<sup>2</sup>  The name `main` points to the last one—until you make a *new* commit.  Then new commit `E` springs into being, pointing backwards to `D`, and Git updates the name `main` to point to `E`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E   <--main
```

---

<sup>2</sup>This is technically impossible, and Git doesn't really try to prevent anyone else from getting the same hash ID *except* by using cryptographic trickery to make it so unlikely that we don't have to worry about it.  Nobody will *accidentally* re-use your hash IDs.  The crypto makes it hard to do it on purpose, too.

---

#### Driving back into the past

But what happens when you want to visit an *old* commit?  You ran:

```
git checkout d33795596001197f382038a72d20faf0cfbe7ab7
```

to tell Git to erase, from your work area, all the files that are safely stored forever in commit `D`, and go back to commit `B`: extract the stored-forever files from commit `B` into your work area.  Git did that, and then `git log` showed you commits `B` and `A` and stopped.  Why?

#### Git uses your HEAD to be able to see things

Git has a very special name, `HEAD`, that is not a *branch* name at all.<sup>3</sup>  Instead, this name `HEAD` is normally *attached to* a branch name.  That's what your first `git log` shows:

> ```
> commit 61c71a9e5a6d9e29a4172e687172dd4b8523eb4a (HEAD -> main)
> ```

Git has the name `HEAD` "pointing to" the name `main` here.  I like to draw it this way instead:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main (HEAD)
```

with the name `HEAD` "attached to" the name `main`.  (I also got lazy about drawing the arrows between commits.  Just remember that the connecting lines, from A to B to C to D, are really backwards-pointing arrows.)

Running `git log` tells Git: *First, use `HEAD` to find a commit.*  Since `HEAD` is attached to `main`, Git uses `main` to find commit `D`.  The `git log` command then shows you commit `D`—well, shows it by default; there are options you can give `git log` to change this—and then follows `D`'s arrow back to `C` and shows `C`.  Then `git log` follows `C`'s arrow to `B`, and shows `B`, and follows `B`'s arrow to `A` and shows `A`.  Commit `A` has no backwards arrow, so `git log` can finally stop.

When you `git checkout` a commit by its *hash ID*, however, Git goes into what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  Here, the name `HEAD` is no longer attached to a branch name.  Instead, it points directly to a commit.  If you choose commit `B`, you get this:

```
A--B   <-- HEAD
    \
     C--D   <-- main
```

The `git log` command works as before: it uses `HEAD` to find a commit.  But this time `HEAD` finds commit `B`, not name `main` and then commit `D`.  So `git log` shows `B`, and follows `B`'s arrow back to `A` and shows `A`, and then runs out of commits to show and stops.

If you want to see all your commits, you can:

```
git checkout main
```

which switches back to branch `main`, re-attaching your `HEAD`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and now you're starting `git log` from the end of the road—the last commit on `main`—and you'll see all four commits.  **Or**, you can run:

```
git log main
```

which tells `git log` that it should use the name `main` to look up the commit to start with.  This will find commit `D`, even though `HEAD` is still pointing directly to commit `B`.

---

<sup>3</sup>It's technically possible to create a branch named `HEAD`.  Don't do it.

---

#### More than one branch name

Once you understand the above, you're ready to handle multiple branch names.  Suppose we have this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and we create a new *name*, such as `develop`, pointing to commit `D`, by running:

```
git branch develop
```

We now have this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

That is, *both names*, `develop` and `main`, point to commit `D`.  The special name `HEAD` is currently attached to the name `main` though.  Let's make a new commit *on* `main`, commit `E`, and draw it in:

```
           E   <-- main (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- develop
```

Commit `E` is now the *latest* commit on `main`, while commit `D` *continues to be the latest commit on `develop`*.

If you now run:

```
git checkout develop
```

or:

```
git switch develop
```

to switch to branch `develop`, we get:

```
           E   <-- main
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commit `E` still exists, but Git will take all of `E`'s *files* out of our work area, and put in all of `D`'s files instead.  The name `HEAD` is now attached to the name `develop`, not the name `main`, so `git log` will show commits `D`, `C`, `B`, and `A` and then stop.  Running `git log main` will show `E`, then `D`, then `C`, and so on.

Note that commits up through `D` are on *both branches*.  But now that we're on `develop` instead of `main`, let's make another new commit:

```
           E   <-- main
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           F   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commits `A` through `D` are still on both branches, but now `main` and `develop` each have one commit that the other branch doesn't have.  The two names pick the latest commits, which are `E` and `F`.  `E` is the latest *`main`*-branch commit and `F` is the latest *`develop`*-branch commit.  They're both "the latest commit"!  If we make another new commit on `develop`, like this:

```
           E   <-- main
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           F--G   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

then the two latest commits are now `E` and `G`.  *Each branch name "means" that particular commit, which is by definition the latest commit on that branch.*  Moreover, *all* the commits you (or Git) can find by starting at that "latest" commit, and working backwards, are "on" that branch.  So when we have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

we have three latest commits, and commits up through `H` are on all three branches.  Pick one name to check out, and that's the set of commits you'll see with `git log`; the files in your work area will be those from that latest—or *tip*—commit.

Note that the *commits* never change: once you make a commit, it is good forever.  However, we *find* commits through branch names, and those *do* move about.  If we take the last example and move the name `br2` back one hop:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- br2
           \
            L   ???
```

we may never be able to *find* commit `L` again.  It has become "lost", as there's no way to recover its hash ID.  As long as we can find `J` and `K`, though, we can't lose `H`, even if we completely *delete* the name `main`.  Deleting that name just means we no longer have *direct access* to commit `H`: we have to find it by working back one step from `K`, or two from `J`.

Comment: In your very last example, what specific command would move br2 to point at K when so far it was pointing at L ?

Comment: @Tryer: If you're "on" `br2`, `git reset HEAD^` (add soft/mixed/hard flags as desired to affect index and/or working tree as desired). If not, `git branch -f br2 br2^`. Those are not the only commands that will do it but those are the two I'd use as examples.